# Prolog - Is this negation by failure correct?

Tags: prolog, negation

Using `!` and `fail`, I'm trying negation by failure.

The method below however gives me the warning: Singleton variables: [X].

However, it seems to work so I'm wondering if there's anything wrong with my method of doing it:

```
likes(vincent, big_kahuna_burger).
neg(X) :- X, !, fail.
neg(X).
```

So calling `neg(likes(vincent, big_kahuna_burger))` will return `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation of `neg` is correct. It's just giving you a warning because in the second rule, `X` is never used. If you write

```
neg(X) :- X, !, fail.
neg(_).
```

you will get no warning.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the matter: you can name your variables, in swi at least, with a starting `_` to indicate that they won't be used more than once. This way you can still add a meaningful name to a variable and preserve a valuable information. Here is an example with `member/2` :

```
member(Element, [Element|Tail]).
member(Element, [Head|Tail]) :-
    member(Element, Tail).
```

would produce warnings, but

```
member(Element, [Element|_Tail]).
member(Element, [_Head|Tail]) :-
    member(Element, Tail).
```

would not, yet you have preserved all the information contained in your variables names.

Though, you have to note that a variable starting with a `_` isn't the same thing that the anonymous variable, for example, in this code (which is kinda useless):

```
member(_, _).
```

the two `_` are different variables, while in this code:

```
member(_A, _A).
```

the two `_A` are the same variable.